# Can't figure out how to make substr_compare work properly (PHP)

Tags: php, html

So I have this basic script:

```
/*check if email is valid*/
if (substr_compare ( $email , '@' , 0 )>0)
{   
/*put user to temporary database*/      
echo 'registration script';
}else{echo 'wrong mail';};
```

What I want to do is I want to check if string contains symbol '@' (if mail is valid).
But it does not work:
when I set up variable $email to something like 'name' = the function returns '1', though I assume it should return 0 or -1, as the letter is not there.
What am I missing?

Comment: Checking for an @ is not a way to check for good emails. Regular expressions work much better; Google "regular expression email" and you'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the sctring *contains* another substring you need to use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (not compare function such as `substr_compare`):

```
if (strpos($email, '@') !== null) { ... }
```

And yes, the way you check for email address is pretty weak. Use regular expressions or built in PHP [filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) like

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) to validate the email, this way is much more robust.

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This (email) email address is considered valid.";
} else {
    echo "wrong email";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string contains '@' in the entered email address, You can easily check with strpos funciton:

```
if (strpos($_POST['email'], '@') !== false) {
    echo 'The email address has @ in it.';
}
```

Technically, strpos() function returns the index location of the first character of the specified substring if it finds it. If it fails in locating the substring in the string, it returns boolean false. As it’s possible that the substring may start in the very beginning of the father string thus strpos() returning 0 which is interpreted as false in PHP, a absolute comparison of !== is required.